# Construct circuit using only NAND and NOT GATES

Tags: boolean-logic

[image: AD + AC + B'D']

In the image above, circuit is Sum of Products

(B’+D’) (A+D) (A+C)

The image below is my attempt on using NAND and NOT gates only. However, my senses is telling me that I am doing it wrongly. Please help!

[image: ((A'D')'(A'C')'(B'D')')']

Comment: What tool did you use to create that schematic?

Answer (score 1):

The first circuit actually implements

[image: AD + AC + B'D']

which is this circuit:

[image: AD + AC + B'D']

Using [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), this is equivalent to

[image: ((AD)'(AC)'(B'D')')']

which is this circuit:

[image: ((AD)'(AC)'(B'D')')']

This Python program can be used to compare the circuits:

```py
import itertools
# Create all the possible input combinations
x = (True, False)
comb = set(itertools.product(x, x, x, x))
# AD + AC + B'D'
def c1(a, b, c, d):
    return ((a and d) or (a and c) or ((not b) and (not d)))
# ((AD)'(AC)'(B'D')')'
def c2(a, b, c, d):
    return not ((not (a and d)) and (not (a and c)) and (not ((not b) and (not d))))
# For each input, verify that the results are the same
for x in comb:
    r1 = c1(*x)
    r2 = c2(*x)
    if r1 != r2:
        print "Error: Input %s produced %s != %s" % (x, r1, r2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all AND gates with NAND gates and just negate the result. I can see that you negated the inputs, which is wrong because:

```
(ab)'  !=  a'b'
```

As an example think about signals (a, b) = (1, 0). If you negate them and calculate output, you get 0. If you first calculate and then negate output, you get 1.

About the OR gate:

```
a + b + c  ->  ((a + b + c)')'  ->  (a'b'c')'
```

So OR gate is NAND gate with all signals negated.